# geocoding with batch procedure

Tags: perl, geocoding, batch-processing

Is there a way to obtain and store the latitude and longitude from addresses?
Customer I work for has a need to enrich their master database with geographic information.
Clearly, the database contains millions of addresses.

For this reason I thought to implement a batch procedure, for example in perl. In fact, I found several CPAN modules, but I have some doubts about the legality of their use in the context described above.

Can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: Are you having technical issues or legal issues?  We can help with the former, but we can't advise on the latter.

Comment: I would like to have some advice on how to do technically. In addition, if you could and if someone had already had to deal with a similar problem, figure out how to have been circumvented or resolved any legal issues surrounding the use batch procedures. Thanks

Comment: For technical advice, what issues have you run into?  Did you try any of the modules you mentioned?  Are you using a specific geocoding service?  For example, I've used Google's geocoding service in the past through their JSON API and it's worked well for me.  For any legal issues, again, Stack Overflow is not legal counsel.  We aren't lawyers, we don't know your jurisdiction, we don't know your company, your vendor, your contracts, etc.  Even if somebody here does offer legal advice, I urge you _not_ to take it.

Answer (score 2):

Geocoding API via REST is usually rate limited (also due to legal reasons).
You can use OpenStreetMap geocoder which is less restricted and has a maintained CPAN module [Geo::Coder::Many::OSM](https://metacpan.org/module/Geo%3a%3aCoder%3a%3aMany%3a%3aOSM).
If the remote API speed is not enough for you, it is possible to deploy a local OpenSource geocoder: http://www.gisgraphy.com/

Answer (score 2):

If granularity at level of cities is OK for you, then check [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/). You can use it offline.

Answer (score 0):

I work at [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) where we provide batch geocoding services. Generally, less than an hour for a million addresses, and we've had people run 180 million+ through our system before. (You'll also be able to verify the existence of the address in the process.)

We don't have total rooftop-level data like Google does (but for most applications it's quite good enough until we can improve our data as well as Google has done). There's no TOS which limit the number of queries you can make or the number of addresses you can geocode. It comes in both list upload and API flavors.